# How to Disable a Multi Select Dropdown automatically when page is loaded and enable it based on the value of another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 2 MultiSelect dropdowns. Here is what I want my code to do:

1. I want the multiselect02 field to be disabled when page is loaded.
2. Only when I select option "Item2" from multiselect01, I want multiselect02 field to be enabled.

```
    <select id="multiselect01" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Item1</option>
        <option>Item2</option>
        <option>Item3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="multiselect02" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Item41</option>
        <option>Item42</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: First, add css class such as `.banned` with disable options. Second, add add `.banned` to `#multiselect02` to disable it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#multiselect01').change(function () {
        let bEnable = false;

        $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
            let selText = $(this).text() || '';
            if (selText == 'Item2')
                bEnable = true;
        });
        if (bEnable) {
            $('#multiselect02').removeClass('banned');
        }
        else {
            $('#multiselect02').addClass('banned');
        }  
    });
});
```

```css
.banned {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiselect01" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Item1</option>
        <option>Item2</option>
        <option>Item3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="multiselect02" multiple="multiple" class="banned">
        <option>Item41</option>
        <option>Item42</option>
    </select>
```